# Using every value(from hash) to get data from Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, perl

I have a hash with values that are comma-separated strings. I want to use both the values for fetching data from a database and use them for insertion in a different table. How should I do them?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

use Getopt::Long; 
use Data::Dumper ;
use DBI; 

my $dbh_oracle = DBI->connect(
    "dbi:Oracle:pro", 
    'user',
    'change', 
    {AutoCommit => 0, RaiseError => 1, LongReadLen => 1000000}
) or die "Cant connect to oracle\n";

my $company = "select id from company where company_name = ?";
my $insert =  "insert into CODE_DATA values(CODE_SEQ.nextval,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,sysdate)";

my $array_values = {
  'Phase' => '',
  'Code' => 'SQ',
  'Year' => '1965 , 1967',
  'Company' => 'ROFL , TOL',
  'stem' => 'TRM , TRX, TRY',
  'ID' => '1697794',
  'BOX' => ''
};

if ( $array_values->{'Company'} ne '' ) {

    my $sthgetCompany = $dbh_oracle->prepare($company)
            or die 'Cannot prepare the statement'. $dbh_oracle->errstr;

    $sthgetCompany->execute($arrar_values->{'Company'})
            or die 'Cannot execute the statement'. $dbh_oracle->errstr;

    # Since it has more than one value it dies. I need to take one value then another to get the ID.

    my $company_id = $sthgetCompany->fetch()
            or die 'Cannot fetch the results.'. $dbh_oracle->errstr;
}
else {

}
```

Comment: What did you try? Did you think about using split? Your company field is 'FROM , TO', so try `my ($company_from, $company_to) = split(/\s*,\s*/, $array_values->{'Company'};` then do something appropriate.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for. The SQL code for `$sthgetCompany` doesn't take any parameters at all. That is why you are getting a *too many values" warning — you are giving it *one* parameter when it is expecting *none*. I guess you need a `WHERE` clause in there?

Comment: *Please* ***always*** `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of *every* Perl program that you write, especially if you are asking others for help with it.

Comment: I tried with split but I didn't know how to get each of them without using a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [bind_param](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.633/DBI.pm#bind_param) with prepare method. For example:

```
 my $sthgetCompany = $dbh_oracle->prepare($company)
            or die 'Cannot prepare the statement'. $dbh_oracle->errstr;
$sthgetCompany->bind_param(1,$company_name_value);
$sthgetCompany->execute;
```

Comment: Okie so I have used split and List::MoreUtils(each_array) to solve this. Thanks